# Symfony2: manually add a NotBlank constraint

Tags: forms, symfony, constraints

I am dynamically building forms. This works great, but now I need to check that same fields are not empty. The related fields are get from the DB, so I cannot use annotations.

I tried the following:

```
$constraints = array();
$constraints[] = new NotBlank(array('message' => 'Please enter something'));
$params['constraints'] = $constraints;
$formBuilder->add($dynamic_name, $dynamic_type, $params);
```

This works only for the main form (not subforms - whereas I put the 'cascade_validation' => true at each form / subform creation), and the most annoying is that the error message isn't displayed (whereas custom errors that I manage in an external validator are displayed fine).

Any idea?

Comment: The main form needs to have "valid" constraint for the subform, unless I am missing something from your question.